# prime numbers in vector code

Tags: java

When I run my program I would like just the prime numbers to print. For some reason all the entered numbers print. Can someone help me with where my error is.

```
for(int i=3; i*i<=n; i+=2) {
    if((n%i)==0) {  
        isPrime=false;
    }
    if(n%2==0) {
        isPrime = false;
    }
    else {
        isPrime = true;
    }
}
if(isPrime = true) {
    mVector.add(n);
}
if(n==0){
    System.out.println(mVector);
    break;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code?

Comment: The above code  was not valid until I added a missing `{`. Be sure that your actual code looks similar to the above.  By the way, by adding `2` to an odd number (`3`), you will never have an even number.

Comment: @user2255619 You should consider stepping through your code in a debugger. I'd say the problem is in that you set `isPrime=true` for every odd number. (Which is every number you iterate over as pickypg noticed.) You should separate the primality check into its own function and `return false;` when you find a divisor.

Answer (score 4):

`isPrime = true` is an assignment of `true` to the variable `isPrime`. An assignment expression will always return the assigned value (i.e. `true`). You need comparison:

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

But really just

```
if (isPrime)
```

would be better.

Also, if `n` is odd, you will keep changing `isPrime` to `true` for every iteration of the for-loop:

```
if(n%2==0) {
    isPrime = false;
}
else {
    isPrime = true;
}
```

I suggest something like:

```
boolean isPrime = true;
if (n%2 == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
}
for (int i = 3; isPrime && i*i <= n; i += 2) {
    if(n%i == 0) {  
        isPrime = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isPrime == true) //change = to ==
```

It might help you